# How do I add new properties to an existing custom object and add values to the newly added properties in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have to create a report which reads two different files, they are `.properties` files, one is custom version of the original. I am currently reading both files using `Get-Content` and pass it to pileline and `foreach-object`ing and here I am creating a new `[pscustomobject]`. It is working fine for original file, but I am not able to add the custom version of the file:

```
$config = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Config.properties' 
$custom = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Custom\Config.properties'

$orig_obj = $config | % {
  $item = $_ -split '=';
  $features = [PSCustomObject]@{
     'Server'  = "$(hostname.exe)"
     'Feature' = $item[0]
     'Value'   = $item[1]
  } 
  $feature
}
```

Above returns this:

```
Server          ConfFeature                      ConfValue                                                                                                                                                                      
------          -----------                      ---------                                                                                                                                                                      
srv1            client.number                    111                                                                                                                                                                          
srv1            FEAT1                            101
```

Now I want to do the `custom` file , but I want to add the `features` and `values` as a new columns to the above output:

```
Server          ConfFeature                      ConfValue     CustomFeature     CustomValue                                                                                                                                                                 
------          -----------                      ---------     -------------     -----------                                                                                                                                                                
srv1            FEAT2                            111           FEAT2             222                                                                                                                                                                   
srv1            FEAT1                            101           FEAT1             201
```

how do I add the new columns?

Comment: Can you post an example of the file contents for a working and a failing file?  Seems like the issue is that you aren't parsing the failed file properly (probably due to different formatting).

Comment: sorry for me not beaing clear, nothing is failing, after I read original file and created the columns, I need to read another file with same format but different content (costomised), then I need to add two new columns showing the read content from the second file, btw, all files have same format: key=value, e.g.: FEAT1=101, per line.

Comment: Ah.  I misunderstood the question.  You can add new properties to an existing object (not just your own `[PsCustomObject]`) by using [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want cross by feature...

```
#import and split by '=' and add header Fetaure and value
$custom = import-csv 'D:\Config.properties' -Delimiter '=' -Header Feature, Value

#import and split by '=' and add header Fetaure and value and add property Server, CustomFeature  CustomValue
$config = import-csv -Path 'D:\Custom\Config.properties'  -Delimiter '=' -Header Feature, Value, Server, CustomFeature  CustomValue  


$Result_obj = $config | %{

  #set hostname
  $_.Server=$env:COMPUTERNAME

  $CurrentFeature = $_.Feature

  #take first row with the same feature into custom file
  $CustomItem=$custom | where Feature -eq $CurrentFeature | select -First 1

  if ($CustomItem -eq $null)
  {
    $_.CustomFeature=$null
    $_.CustomValue=$null
  }
  else 
  {
    $_.CustomFeature=$CustomItem.Feature
    $_.CustomValue=$CustomItem.Value
  }

  $_
}

#show result
$Result_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

To create new "columns" you'll want to use the Add-Member command. What you will actually be doing is adding new properties to the existing object. Here's an example:

```
$feature | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ColumnName" -NotePropertyValue "Value"
```

Here's a link to the Add-Member documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.1